# How to add number value to MySQL using text box in CakePHP 3?

Tags: mysql, input

I want to add the value of the dropdown list in MySQL but I always get the 0 value in the database. Please help. Here is my code

```
<select class="form-control" name="cat_id" type="text">
     <?php foreach($query_cat as $key_cat => $value_cat){?>
     <option value"cat_id"><?=$value_cat['cat_name'];?></option>
     <?php } ?>
</select>
```

I have two tables, group and category.
The options that are in the dropdown list is form category table. 
I want the number value of the cat_id to be added in the group table as a foreign key.

Comment: i'm sorry, this is the full code:



<select class="form-control" name="cat_id" type="text">
            

<?php foreach($query_cat as $key_cat => $value_cat){?>




                <option value"cat_id"><?=$value_cat['cat_name'];?>





</option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>

Comment: You have problem in your HTML

change `<option value"cat_id">` and write proper value there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - you are missing `=` on value and not using the array with the real ID `cat_id`:

```
<select class="form-control" name="cat_id" type="text">
    <?php 
        foreach($query_cat as $key_cat => $value_cat) { 
            echo '<option value="'.$value_cat['cat_id'].'">'.$value_cat['cat_name'].'</option>';
        } 
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: it's stil not adding. :( the format for my cat id is "int" in sql, is it correct?

Comment: it's still not working. can you suggest me what should i do?. I'm kinda new to this stuff. hehe. :) thank you.

Comment: thank you. :) i'll try that one. :) thanks for the big help. :)